# regular expression

Tags: automata

I would like to write the regular expression for the set of
              all binary strings where 
              there are no three consecutive 0's.

The following strings are part of the language:

a) strings of the form $1,11,111,...$

b) strings $\{ 0, 01,011,0111,...\}$

d) strings $\{00, 001,0011,00111,..\}$

So,the regular expression is:
$$ (1+01+001)^*$$

Is this a correct regular expression for the given language?

Comment: Possibly belonging to stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex?

Comment: Or maybe [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Not quite --- your expression doesn't allow the string 0, nor the string 00.

Answer (score 6):

The correct expression would be
$$ (1+01+001)^*(\epsilon+0+00)$$
so that it also accepts words ending in up to two $0$s.

Answer (score 1):

A more precise expression would be

`0+00+(1+01+001)*`

so you will be able to accept 0 or 00...

Comment: What about 100?

Comment: you are right...sorry!